# Set position relative but computed position is static in devtools

Tags: css, css-position

I have a strange behavior with CSS within a table.

I set the `position` to value `relative` on tr elements of an HTML table but I see in devtools (tab "computed") that the value is actually `static`. Moreover, if I click on the source for the `position` property, I can see that the specified value is `relative`.

[image]

[image]

I test in Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) on Linux.

Any idea? Thanks for your help!